# Delete button Yajra Datatable laravel 7 (http://localhost:8000/articles 405 (Method Not Allowed))

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-7

I tried to make datatable with action in it. It works but in my console log have error `DELETE http://localhost:8000/articles 405 (Method Not Allowed)`
I make this code based on what i get on internet but now i'm stuck cannot solve the problem

Route `Route::resource('articles', 'ArticleController');`

On the table `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{!! csrf_token() !!}" />`

Controller

```
$url_delete = 'articles/'.$article->id;
return"
<button data-remote='$url_delete' type='button' rel='tooltip' title='Remove'
   class='btn btn-danger btn-simple btn-xs btn-delete'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i>
</button>";
```

Javascript

```
$('#article-table').on('click', '.btn-delete[data-remote]', function (e) {
            confirm('Are you sure delete this data?');
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            var url = $(this).data('remote');
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'DELETE',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {method: '_DELETE', submit: true}
            }).always(function (data) {
                $('#article-table').DataTable().draw(false);
            });
        });
```

Comment: you are passing wrong url

Comment: what do you mean? it can delete the data but there is an error @VikasKatariya

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "headers" with "XMLHttpRequest" ?

```
headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token, // $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
}
```

Also I recommend to use "data._method" property like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "POST", // if you want, you can check with DELETE too
    data: {
        _method: 'delete', // <---
        submit: true,
        _token: token
    },
    success: function(data) {
        //...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> DELETE http://localhost:8000/articles 405 (Method Not Allowed)

That's mean no delete method on `/articles` and I think it's the wrong URL. The right URL should `/articles/id` which, id is article id.

Make sure `$url_delete` is right, maybe `$article->id` is empty.

and another posibility is you call the wrong element. Your js script is `$('#article-table').on('click', '.btn-delete[data-remote]',` but no `btn-delete` class on your shared code, you only have `btn-hapus` class.

Comment: sorry it's a typo

Comment: what about my first possibility?  did you make sure `$article->id` is not empty?

Comment: I'm sure. it can delete perfectly but i just got an error 405 (Method Not Allowed)